# Angular: Pass route data via link parameters array

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing

In Angular, I can define a route with data like so:

```
{
 path: '/user/:id', 
 component: UserComponent, 
 data: {cache: {use: true, class: MyCacheClass}}
}
```

I would then be able to inject `ActivatedRoute` in my component and access the route data.

I can also link to the component in a template with the routerLink directive by using a link parameters array like so:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user', id]">Profile</a>
```

If I wanted to pass the route data via a template routerLink I'm not sure how. The route data is not part of the route, so I couldn't do:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user', id, 
{cache: {use: true, class: MyCacheClass}}]">
Profile</a>
```

If I do this, Angular will try to navigate to:

> /user/123;cache=[Object]

Can route data be passed via the routerLink directive and its link parameters array so that I can fetch it from the `ActivatedRoute`?

PS: To be clear, I am not asking for how I can encode the object within the url itself; I'm asking how to pass it to routerLink so that I can get it by injecting `ActivatedRoute` or `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` and fetching their `data` property

Answer (score 4):

You can't. It's against Angular Router design.

Folks deal with such pattern with state management libs such as NGRX/NGXS/Akita or self-designed services.

If your objects are persistent, I'd recommend creating some hash map, and encoding the key in the URL. That way when you navigate from bookmarks etc, exact state could be restored.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can but with simple (not nested) objects only.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user', id, 
{cache: true, class: MyCacheClass, cacheId = 723 }]">
Profile</a>
```

The URL

```
/user/123;cache=true;class=MyCacheClass;cacheId=723
```

Then use a service or a mechanism on the target page to reload the entire object instead, by using a unique ID as in the example or something similar.

**I would recommend** then to simply the routeData there and use an injected class, for example - `StoreService` from which you can retrieve the cache by using the ID or other unique

Since it will be a singleton you will be able to access the data between views.. without having to mess around with complex route parameters.

You will find you need to add more things in later, then this will make it allot easier.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  What I'm trying to pass isn't a simple object, so it can't be expressed as a url parameter.  It's an object that contains objects.  I agree 100% that it should not be in the route.  I'm asking whether the route data can be set via routerLink, not how to pass an object in the route itself.  The service injection is my plan B

Comment: To be honest.. the Service Injection should have been plan A - It makes going forward allot easier. I ran into a similar issue and realised this too :D  You could probably encode the complex object into a base64 route parameters... but that is very limited and convoluted.

Comment: I don't think I'm explaining it well. I don't want the object in the route.  I want it in the route data; what you access by injecting the `ActivatedRoute` or `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` and accessing their data property

Comment: Basically the equivalent of my first snippet within the question

Comment: Ohh - yes I see. OK - But It seems to be trying to pass it through the URL. Which is annoying.

Comment: The documentation does not show any way to pass router data in using `routerLink` as a bindable link -  have you got a link to where you found this?

Comment: If I had such a link, I would have the answer and I wouldn't need to ask the question :-)  I'm asking the question because it would be convenient if it were possible but I can't see a way to make it happen.  So I wondered if someone else knows of a way.

Comment: Yes. I can see now. ON the Angular Documentation they use simple objects. It does not seem it supports complex objects. https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink  - `For instance ['/team', teamId, 'user', userName, {details: true}] means that we want to generate a link to /team/11/user/bob;details=true` Which implies the RouteData using this way is passed via the URL and not within the Router Singleton, as if you would be using it from TypeScript. A work around would be to serialise your object to base64 and deserialise it on the other end.. but that is not KISS

Comment: Just Googling around it seems like many people tried this since Angular 2 and it has been mentioned that complex objects are not supported. Which is understandable because the URL path is limited to 2083 characters.. so could truncate big objects. You may need to reconsider how you are transitioning between pages and reload the data using a simple mechanism. Like injected Angular Singletons, Cookies, LocalStorage, etc

Comment: This `;` is the syntax of matrix parameters, somewhat buried here: https://angular.io/guide/router#heroes-list-optionally-selecting-a-hero

Comment: Yea- I have never come across that before. Its not a W3C standard. I see where it comes from now, as its a marker that Angular Router uses to find where to start deserialising simple "Route Data" - It looks like `key:value` separator syntax. Hence why complex objects don't seem to work.

Comment: Re: "the URL path is limited to 2083 characters...You may need to reconsider"  Please remember I don't want to show it in the URL path; that was not my question

Comment: I know.. but using THAT method will put it into the URL because that is how it passes data without using the injection services. That is what I am saying :D So again.. try and use the services injection and a simpler method